# Как получить все переменные класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Допустим у меня есть класс Class, и мне нужно получить все атрибуты, которые есть в методе **init**, НО также мне еще нужно отделить от них self, который находится в аргументах метода **init** а не ниже

```py
class Class:
    def __init__(self, name, addr) # --> Хотелось бы получить [name, addr]
        self.name==name
        self.addr=addr
    def Foo(self):pass
```

Если честно то можно и без списка, но это лучший исход событий

Answer (score 0):

[inspect.getfullargspec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec):

```
import inspect


class Class:
    def __init__(self, name, addr): # --> Хотелось бы получить [name, addr]
        self.name=name
        self.addr=addr
    def Foo(self):pass


print(inspect.getfullargspec(Class.__init__).args[1:])
```

> ```
> $ python args.py
> ['name', 'addr']
> ```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает